# spl-token library in xNFT not working

Tags: anchor, metaplex

I was trying to work with the @solana/spl-token package in my xNFT with the latest xNFT-starter repository.

When I use any function I get the following error:

```
Can't import the named export 'PublicKey' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) node_modules/@solana/buffer-layout-utils/lib/esm/web3.mjs
```

As far as I was able to figure out, that means that mjs files not being compiled by the Metro Bundler.

I tried multiple way adding the extension in the metro.config.js file but couldn't get it to work.

Highly looking forward to any hints how to solve this. A couple other people had that issue as well

Comment: Can you share some code snippets? Possibly the import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error i think its more to do with the pubkeys than with the token package. I havent used spl-token in my xNFT but solana web3 works fine. WIll do some testing with token in the next week and circle back.

Make sure you are including the pubkey type, like so:
import {
Connection,
Keypair,
SystemProgram,
LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
Transaction,
TransactionInstruction,
sendAndConfirmTransaction,
PublicKey,
} from '@solana/web3.js';

also make sure to run yarn install, update to the most recent version of the xNFT starter version and cli, and install the spl-token before building.

If you share code, will be able to help with a bit more precision.

Comment: Capitalization and spelling errors